# Unicode encoder error in LatentDirichletAllocation

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, nlp, cluster-analysis

When I tried to perform LatentDirichlet Allocation on an array,it kept showing

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\_lda.py in fit(self, X, y)
    624         last_bound = None
    625         n_jobs = effective_n_jobs(self.n_jobs)
--> 626         with Parallel(n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=max(0, self.verbose - 1)) as parallel:
    627             for i in range(max_iter):
    628                 if learning_method == "online":

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __enter__(self)
    723     def __enter__(self):
    724         self._managed_backend = True
--> 725         self._initialize_backend()
    726         return self
    727 

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in _initialize_backend(self)
    733         """Build a process or thread pool and return the number of workers"""
    734         try:
--> 735             n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,
    736                                              **self._backend_args)
    737             if self.timeout is not None and not self._backend.supports_timeout:

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in configure(self, n_jobs, parallel, prefer, require, idle_worker_timeout, **memmappingexecutor_args)
    492                 SequentialBackend(nesting_level=self.nesting_level))
    493 
--> 494         self._workers = get_memmapping_executor(
    495             n_jobs, timeout=idle_worker_timeout,
    496             env=self._prepare_worker_env(n_jobs=n_jobs),

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     18 
     19 def get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs):
---> 20     return MemmappingExecutor.get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)
     21 
     22 

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\executor.py in get_memmapping_executor(cls, n_jobs, timeout, initializer, initargs, env, temp_folder, context_id, **backend_args)
     40         _executor_args = executor_args
     41 
---> 42         manager = TemporaryResourcesManager(temp_folder)
     43 
     44         # reducers access the temporary folder in which to store temporary

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in __init__(self, temp_folder_root, context_id)
    529             # exposes exposes too many low-level details.
    530             context_id = uuid4().hex
--> 531         self.set_current_context(context_id)
    532 
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in set_current_context(self, context_id)
    533     def set_current_context(self, context_id):
    534         self._current_context_id = context_id
--> 535         self.register_new_context(context_id)
    536 
    537     def register_new_context(self, context_id):

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_new_context(self, context_id)
    558                 new_folder_name, self._temp_folder_root
    559             )
--> 560             self.register_folder_finalizer(new_folder_path, context_id)
    561             self._cached_temp_folders[context_id] = new_folder_path
    562 

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py in register_folder_finalizer(self, pool_subfolder, context_id)
    588         # semaphores and pipes
    589         pool_module_name = whichmodule(delete_folder, 'delete_folder')
--> 590         resource_tracker.register(pool_subfolder, "folder")
    591 
    592         def _cleanup():

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in register(self, name, rtype)
    189         '''Register a named resource, and increment its refcount.'''
    190         self.ensure_running()
--> 191         self._send('REGISTER', name, rtype)
    192 
    193     def unregister(self, name, rtype):

D:\Anacondo\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py in _send(self, cmd, name, rtype)
    202 
    203     def _send(self, cmd, name, rtype):
--> 204         msg = '{0}:{1}:{2}\n'.format(cmd, name, rtype).encode('ascii')
    205         if len(name) > 512:
    206             # posix guarantees that writes to a pipe of less than PIPE_BUF

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 18-19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The following code was provided by the instructor and yet no changes have been made.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("android.csv", sep=",",  thousands=",")

df["Number of ratings"] = df["Number of ratings"].astype(int) # fix data type
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["App"]).reset_index(drop=True)

df.head(n=3)
permission_columns = list(df.columns[10:])
app_names = list(df["App"])
app_ratings = np.array(df["Number of ratings"])
df_perms = df[permission_columns]
X = df_perms.values
```

Below is my code to use TF-IDF and LatentDirichletAllocation to fit the data.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(X)

# convert sparse matrix to numpy array
X_tfidf = X_tfidf.toarray()
%%time
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
n_topics = 10
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=n_topics, max_iter=10,
                                learning_method='online',
                                n_jobs=-1, random_state=3)
lda.fit(X_tfidf)
```

However,it kept showing UnicodeEncodingError. I tried to add

```
df = pd.read_csv("android.csv", sep=",",  thousands=",",engine='python',encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

it doesn't work.I tried several different encoding methods,it doesn't work either.
Is there anyway I can solve the issue? I think there might be something wrong with the X_tfidf array,but I can't tell.
Any help will be appreciated!

I tried with another array which is not taken from this dataset.It still doesn't work and shows the same error & traceback.

Edit:this works fine with Google Colab.There might be something wrong with my Jupyter Notebook settings.

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. (2) Are the errors always the same when you try different encodings?

Comment: `UnicodeEncodeError` is a *writing* or *printing* error.  Is your terminal misconfigured?  A `pd.read_csv` would have a `UnicodeDecodeError` not `UnicodeEncodeError`.  Show the full traceback.

Comment: I just edited the question. The errors are always the same when I tried different encodings

Comment: The failing line is in a library *explicitly* encoding in ASCII.  Use a debugger and see how the non-ASCII characters are getting into the data.  Probably, remove them from your "android.csv" or file a bug with the library, but nothing we can do to help without a [mcve].

Comment: I tried using another array which is not taken from this android dataset, it stills shows the same error and doesn't work. I'm guessing that's not something with the dataset...